# Can you help me figuring out, what this Snipped of Java-code is supposed to do?

Tags: java, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I found this Java code in a job interview question and tried to figure it out. (I am a Smalltalker and am less familar with the syntax of Java as maybe I thought).

As far as I can see, it spawns a thread for every row in a data matrix. The thread seems to process each column in the row-vector pairwise. It checks if the first item in the pair is bigger then the second. If true it increments a global counter(?) and does something to the data, that I don't understand (What's "or" defined to do with integers in Java?).

I believe it is somehow broken, too. Can you help me figure it out? I want to understand what's going on.

```
public static int process(int [][] data) {
    final Object[] c = new Object[]{0};
    Object[] p = new Object[data.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        final int [] r = data[i];
        p[i] = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for (int s0 = 0, s1 = 0; s0 < r.length - 1; s0++, s1 = s0 + 1) {
                    if (r[s0] > r[s1]) {
                        // what is this next line supposed to do?
                        r[s0] ^= r[s1]; r[s1] ^= r[s0]; r[s0] ^= r[s1];
                        // does this next line increase a global counter?
                        c[0] = ((Integer) c[0]) + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
    return (Integer) c[0];
}
```

Comment: ^ is XOR, not just OR. It will perform XOR for each bit of the integer independently.

Comment: "what is this next line supposed to do" is the famous [XOR Swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).

Comment: Ah, that's the syntax for XOR, makes sense now. I still don't get why anybody would want to swap vars this way in Java. Better let the compiler handle/optimize this. ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several major problems with this code, here's a few:

- The threads are created, but never started.  This means the code they contain will *never* run. For that to occur, the [`start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) method must be called on each thread that is created.
- The threads are not "joined" at the end, so the method will return the value in `c[0]` before the threads have had a chance to perform their calculations.  For that to occur, the [`join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) method must be called on each thread that is created.
- The updating of `c[0]` by the threads is not thread safe.  This data, which is concurrently accessed by multiple threads, needs to be protected locking mechanism of some sort.
- On the first iteration of the inner for loop, both `s0` and `s1` are `0`, on further iterations, `s1` is one ahead of `s2`.  Not knowing what is actually wanted by the algorithm, this may or may not be correct, but looks suspicious.

Additionally, there's a few things that are just odd:

- Why declare a single element array of objects `c`, for it to only have one element, and never be used as an array, but as simple variable.  We probably want to use an [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) here.  That will also solve the concurrent access issue, as `AtomicInteger` provides thread-safety.
- Nothing is typed.  For example the array `p` should be an array of `Thread` objects:

  ```
  Thread p[] = new Thread[data.length];
  ```

  Similarly, the type of `c` should be `Integer[]` (or `AtomicInteger`)

I have annotated the code below:

```
// Method declaration, takes a two-demensional array of integers
public static int process(int [][] data) {
    // Create a one-demensional array of Objects, containing 
    // a single element, `0`.  This will be "auto-boxed" from
    // a primitive int to an Integer object.
    final Object[] c = new Object[]{0};
    // Create a one dimensional array of Objects, of the same
    // size as the first dimension of data
    Object[] p = new Object[data.length];

    // Loop through each index of the array p, declared above
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        // get a reference, r, to the ith "row" of data
        final int [] r = data[i];
        // create a new Thread, and store a reference to it in p[i]
        p[i] = new Thread() {
            // This is the method that will be invoked on a separate
            // thread of execution by the java virtual machine
            public void run() {
                for (int s0 = 0, s1 = 0; s0 < r.length - 1; s0++, s1 = s0 + 1) {
                    if (r[s0] > r[s1]) {
                        // perform an xor-swap of two elements in the
                        // array (as pointed out by Jongware)
                        r[s0] ^= r[s1]; r[s1] ^= r[s0]; r[s0] ^= r[s1];
                        // this access of c[0] is not thread-safe
                        c[0] = ((Integer) c[0]) + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
    // return the value in c[0]
    return (Integer) c[0];
}
```

And here is a version where I've fixed all the things I mention above:

```
public static int process(int [][] data) {
    final AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[data.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        final int [] row = data[i];
        threads[i] = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for (int s0 = 0, s1 = 1; s0 < row.length - 1; s0++, s1 = s0 + 1) {
                    if (row[s0] > row[s1]) {
                        row[s0] ^= row[s1]; row[s1] ^= row[s0]; row[s0] ^= row[s1];
                        c.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        threads[i].start();
    }
    try {
        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    return c.intValue();
}
```

Comment: With the missing pieces filled in, the whole thing looks like a halve baked "Bubble-Sort my 2d array row-wise using threads for parallelism and count the swaps necessary". My Java is really rusty... v_v

Comment: I just added a version with fixes in for you to look at.

Comment: My comment was intended just as a remark regarding my understanding of the programm, not as a request for completion. The extra help is appreciated, though. The structure is almost the same as with a similar Python or Smalltalk programm. But Java is so verbose and complicated looking. ^^